# Received a sticker on my car window on a private company car park

Tags: united-kingdom, civil-law, traffic

Quick story: I parked in my company car park (so I guess its private land), in a place where 'the bay is not marked'. I see many people parking in the same spot, and never have I seen a sticker on their window. It's a large sticker (around half A4 size), stuck to my driver's window. Just a warning not to park there as I am not allowed, with writing that I could barely read. The sticker itself left a lot of glue marks on my window, so I am asking the security company to pay for the damage. Is this allowed?

The response I got is that it's my fault for parking in a place that I shouldn't, but surely they do not have the right to put stickers on my car which do not easily peel off? Can I take this further? And what laws do I / the parking company have in such situation?

From my research, private land owners do not have the right to clamp your car, but I couldn't find any recent news about sticker on cars.

*This occurred in the UK*

Comment: As the security company is a vendor to your employer (or employer's landlord) you may have more traction if you take it up with your boss, facilities manager or HR department. If you're embarrassed to tell them this story, that should indicate if this is an equitable result or not.

Comment: It's glue on glass. It will come out with warm water and soap. Or alcohol, or nail polish remover, or vinegar, or 100 other home appliances. I've had the municipal police do the same on my motorbike leather seat because I parked on a large sidewalk against the wall. Most cities didn't care, this one did (despite not having bike parking spots, I did ask the officer where the nearest one was, and he just shrugged). If they had ruined the leather, it might make sense to try to complain. I still wouldn't see the money most likely, or it'd take forever. For a window with glue? Why even bother?

Comment: Yes, it is allowed for you to ask the security company to pay for "damage".  Yes, you can take this further...  But do you really want to?  Would it take more or less time and effort to escalate the situation vs cleaning off the sticky bits and learning your lesson?

Answer (score 8):

You may be entitled to compensation for reasonable costs related to restoring your window to its previous state. If you sue, you will have to present your actual expenses and show that they are reasonable. Ultimately this boils down to how much it really costs to clean the glue off your window. A safe bet is to take it to a few reputable dealers/shops, get written quotes, go with one in the middle and keep your receipts. Make sure that you are paying only for the actual task at hand, not some sort of "one hour minimum" or "flat rate" charge.

Just to be clear, have you tried soap and warm water? You are never going to come out monetarily ahead in this pursuit.

Answer (score 3):

Just rub it with a tissue soaked in any vegetable oil - all glue will gradually dissolve and disappear. May take a couple of minutes and 3-5 tisues.

To answer your question though, I will cite this [message](https://www.honestjohn.co.uk/forum/post/index.htm?t=54312#m1062495) from somewhere else on the internet:

> S.1(1) Criminal Damage Act 1971 provides that a person is guilty of
>   criminal damage if they intentionally or recklessly destroy or damage
>   property belonging to another without lawful excuse.
>
> Damage is not defined by the Act. The courts have construed the term
>   liberally. Damage is not limited to permanent damage, so smearing mud
>   on the walls of a police cell may be criminal damage. What constitutes
>   damage is a matter of fact and degree and it is for the court, using
>   its common sense, to decide whether what occurred is damage.
>
> Therefore it is arguable that attaching a large sticker with adhesive
>   that is difficult to remove is an offence under the Act. The relevant
>   word is 'arguable' and it is unlikely that a police force would pursue
>   a prosecution in the event of someone placing a sticker on your car
>   window due to the very uncertain nature of the alleged crime. A
>   successful prosecution could be privately pursued but only with strong
>   evidence from reliable witnesses or video evidence.
>
> The courts would probably take a dim view of such a prosecution,
>   viewing it as petty. Even if the prosecution was successful, you would
>   be unlikely to be compensated for the cost of bringing the case.

Answer (score 0):

How hard is it to get a sticker off your window? Regardless of how the sticker got on your window, that's what this will come down to. The answer is that it's not hard, and it shouldn't cause any damage. Even if you have a good case as to why you shouldn't have received a sticker, you are required to mitigate damages. That essentially means that you can't make the situation worse. You can't smash the window and ask them to replace it, for example. So if you don't know how to remove stickers properly and you damage your window, that's on you. If the sticker used a super powerful glue, then you might have something, but how likely is that? Also, did you ask the people who put the sticker on your car how to get it off?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0006JJS30/ref=mp_s_a_1_9?qid=1463144340&sr=8-9&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=glass+scraper

Comment: The stickers are designed and marketed as being *very* difficult to remove... See for example, http://www.myparkingpermit.com/Parking-Stickers/Parking-Violation-Stickers.aspx?engine=adwords&keyword=parked+illegally+stickers&gclid=Cj0KEQjw3-W5BRCymr_7r7SFt8cBEiQAsLtM8ux6eoef0A7iDD5bD8v5Si4fyRXs_qGK2k8QYgdT7FwaAj-M8P8HAQ

Comment: Well... I am not asking you how to remove the sticker am I @Mohair? Not a helpful answer at all... I am asking you about my rights in such a case, and if I can perform any actions against the company. I know exactly how to remove the sticker

Comment: @deeveeABC but that *is* the point. If you "know exactly how to remove the sticker", then you have the ability to make the window as good as it was before, without involving the party who placed it. You're entitled to recover the time and effort required to do so... but if doing it competently requires a *paltry* amount of time and effort, then there's no point.

Answer (score 0):

As @Patrick87 said, they do not have the right to damage your car.  If you suffer genuine loss as a result of there actions, you do have a right of redress.

That said, it might be a bit rude for you to seek recourse as you did commit the first wrong.  Have you tried using methylated spirits or acetone (nail polish remover) to remove the marks ?  Even superglue can be disolved in that !

Answer (score -2):

So in your company car park you got the sticker - why not complain to the company you work for? like the ones who put the sticker on?

Contact your HR department or boss and if they dont take this matter seriously and recompense you to your complete satisfaction then you can  escalate it up the food chain of your firm and ultimately to the industrial tribunal -  I'm sure that will help show how determined you are and other qualities that you have to your bosses which may well be considered in your future career prospects with your said firm who own the car park.

Or contact the police and have them contact your employers - they may not give this a blue light priority though  or just take to court your employers for an amount you think recompenses you.  Money claim online I think it is.

Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score -4):

I think this is vandalism pure and simple. This could also be classed as criminal damage as pointed out earlier. One thing you have not considered is public safety. Let's say the sticker is not easily removed and in order to remove it you must drive to a location with the resources needed to do so i.e. Spirits, vinegar, hot soapy water etc. While travelling your vision is obstructed by an A4 sized piece of paper stuck on your drivers side window. Before you say they won't use one that size, yes they do my partner just had it done to her. Anyway wouldn't you agree that this could endanger the driver, other drivers, cyclists and pedestrians? I believe so. Yes you could argue that you shouldn't drive your car if it is dangerous. Well let's say your phone is dead and you have left your wallet at home or you're just broke until payday. It is late at night, no one is around and all the nearby shops are shut. What else are you suppose to do? Let's say you did manage to remove the sticker yet the residue that remained also caused your vision to be obscured. Now because of this visual obscurity you hit a pedestrian or cyclist or misjudge when giving someone right of way and results in a car accident, is this not endangering the public? Just because someone says No THATS MY SPOT! I like what the guy said about putting a sticker on their car asking that they use a more suitable method like I don't know a folded piece of paper under the windscreen wiper and it is cheaper OMG! Does this mean that takeaway places can just go around sticking offers on your car windows because it would be petty if you took them to court for criminal damage or wanted compensation for the cost of its removal. I could go on and on and on like what if you're allergic to the glue they used and you have a severe reaction resulting in hospitalisation or death. Yes it's an extreme and unlikely event but still possible. I say stick notices on their cameras stating you do not wish nor give consent to them filming you, hence your sticker.